# Php title issue

Tags: php

Hi Ive tried to find an answer to this but nothing seems to be helping

I have  my page setup as

- **index.php, skills.php** and **contact.php**

I also have setup an **include folder** which contains

- **header.php** and  **footer.php**

currently using the include function to put the header and footer within the seperate pages above.

However im trying to write a script for variables that allows

- **$title, $page_width**, **$meta_description, $meta_keywords**

That replace the information in the **header.php** file dependent on which page is loaded above.

Ive tried numerous things but none seem to work, just keep getting php errors.

Thanks for any advice on this

Kris

Answer (score 1):

You may want to call thoses variables from the global variables. Search for php globals.

But I suggest you to use a templating system like smarty or twig, it is a lot easier and cleaner.

Comment: I will keep them in mind thanks, but site is pretty much built now, just struggling with this last bit cheers

Comment: ignore me i'm an idiot..... and tired... All i had to do was place <?
$subtitle = "testsubtitle";
include('_includes/header.php');
?>, before the include "header.php" action...